# disabling specific function to run on only specific environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

**this is the function**

```
    [FunctionName("RetryEventFunction")]
    public void RunQueue([QueueTrigger("%QueueName%", Connection = "StorageAccount")] string input)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info($"CI Receiver: Retry Event Function triggered. Input : {input}");
            var queueMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueModel>(input);
            EventData data = new EventData(queueMessage.Message);
            foreach (var prop in queueMessage.Headers)
            {
                data.Properties.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
            }
           
            if (IsRetryApplicable(data))
            {
                ManageGeoSpetialData(data);
                Log.Info("CI Receiver: Retry Event Function processed successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info("CI Receiver: Retry Event Function skipped after exhausting specified maximum retries");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"CI Receiver: RetryEventFunction Event Consumer fails with Exception {ex.Message}, {ex.InnerException} and Stacktrace : {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
```

I need to make this function only run on STG and PROD environment so i have to disable this function for DEV and INT environment so what should i do?

**and this is the ProcessEvent(data)**

```
    public void ProcessEvent(object data)
    {
        try
        {
            Constants.InitializeConstants(_configuration);
            var eventData = data as EventData;
            object eventType = "";
            object eventAction = "";
            object eventApplicationId = 0;
            eventData.Properties.TryGetValue(EventProperties.EventTypeProperty, out eventType);
            eventData.Properties.TryGetValue(EventProperties.ActionProperty, out eventAction);
            eventData.Properties.TryGetValue(EventProperties.ApplicationIdProperty, out eventApplicationId);
            Model.Properties properties;

            switch (Convert.ToString(eventType))
            {
                case EventTypes.LoaderEventType:
                    AssetEvent assetEvent = eventData.DeserializetoModel<AssetEvent>(Log);
                    properties = assetEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.Properties != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Properties>(assetEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.Properties) : null;
                    Asset loaderAsset = new Asset()
                    {
                        AssetPrimaryId = assetEvent.AssetPrimaryId,
                        AssetID = assetEvent.AssetId,
                        Make = assetEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.Make,
                        SerialNumber = assetEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.SerialNumber,
                        Type = assetEvent.AssetType,
                        UCID = assetEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.Ucid,
                        ApplicationId = Convert.ToInt32(eventApplicationId),
                        EquipmentId = assetEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.EquipmentId,
                        AssetKey = assetEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.AssetKey,
                        Model = properties?.Model
                    };
                    SaveAssetInfo(loaderAsset, Convert.ToString(eventAction));
                    break;
                case EventTypes.PaverEventType:
                    PaverEvent paverEvent = eventData.DeserializetoModel<PaverEvent>(Log);
                    properties = paverEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.Properties != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.Properties>(paverEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.Properties) : null;
                    Asset paverAsset = new Asset()
                    {
                        AssetPrimaryId = paverEvent.Id,
                        AssetID = paverEvent.AssetId,
                        Make = paverEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.Make,
                        SerialNumber = paverEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.SerialNumber,
                        Type = paverEvent.AssetType,
                        UCID = paverEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.Ucid,
                        ApplicationId = Convert.ToInt32(eventApplicationId),
                        EquipmentId = paverEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.EquipmentId,
                        AssetKey = paverEvent.Device.FirstOrDefault()?.AssetKey,
                        Model = properties?.Model
                    };
                    SaveAssetInfo(paverAsset, Convert.ToString(eventAction));
                    break;

catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _qaPublisher.PublishAsync(data, new PublisherProperties { Name = _configuration["QueueName"], StorageConnectionstring = _configuration["StorageAccount"] });
            Log.Error($"CI Receiver - Exception occured during processing event. Exception Details : {ex.Message} and StackTrace : {ex.StackTrace}");
            Log.Info($"For more details check if data is present in Queue: {_configuration["QueueName"]} otherwise ignore this exception");
        }
    }
```

**
i need to change this code to execute only in DEV and INT environment so please share the needed detailed information**

Comment: Get the `Environment` name and Write the `if` condition for `DEV` and `INT` (and write the code in the if condition. `var myEnv=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Environment");`

Comment: or someone can confirm it will be easier if i change in the function.json file to set the function to disable in the DEV and INT function.json file

Comment: It can be done only in the coding part as I have specified above.

Comment: can i please know the reason for that?

Comment: because we have separate config files for the separate environment